# Карта гугл ч/б но с видимыми домами

Tags: google-maps-api

Есть вот такой удобный сервис: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/
Ну и описание api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference?hl=ru

Я не могу добиться, что бы карта была ч/б, но при этом были отдельно видны контуры домов.
Вот стандартное состояние карты, дома видны:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот ч/б вариант, который мне нужен, но контуры домов пропали:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я не могу понять, какая комбинация featureType + elementType отвечает за заливку именно зданий.

Answer (score -1):

Самый простой вариант, играться параметрами `saturation` и `lightness` для всей карты сразу:

```
[
  {
    "stylers": [
      {
        "saturation": -100
      },
      {
        "lightness": -15
      }
    ]
  }
]
```